# How to configure the default path for the packaged Tauri installation package?

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

How to configure the default path for the packaged Tauri installation package?

---

I want to configure the default installation path, but I did not find a good way to query the document.

---

I want to know whether there is a configurable method for this.

[image]

[image]